# How to create/update a ParamMap in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-router

In Angular 5, the Router/ParamMap object is immutable. It can be retrieved from the route and used in a component. However, I have a use case for which modifying the ParamMap would be convenient (and it worked fine with Angular 4).

Previously, I used the `convertToParamMap` function to convert an `Object` to a `ParamMap`. Since updating to Angular 5, the resulting `ParamMap` object's private `params` member loses its prototype and generates an error when I call the resulting `ParamMap`'s `.get(key)` method.

```js
const params = this.routeParams.keys.reduce(
    (pv: Params, cv) => {
        pv[cv] = this.routeParams.get(cv); // <- Error on second call
        return pv;
    },
    Object.create(null) as Params
);
params["changedKey"] = newValue;
this.routeParams= convertToParamMap(params);
```

`this.routeParams` is initially populated from a call to the `ActivatedRoute` instance's `queryParamMap` method and simply setting my component's `routeParams` member to the returned `ParamMap` instance.

On my first pass through the code above, everything works fine. On the second pass, after I've updated the `routeParams` member with the `convertToParamMap` function, I receive this error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'hasOwnProperty'
```

Via the debugger, the `.get(cv)` call is internally calling the `.has(cv)` method, which then calls `this.params.hasOwnProperty(name)` *(`this` = the `ParamMap` object and `name` = `cv`)*. I'm thinking this is a bug in Angular 5, but I'm looking for an alternative or workaround until it gets fixed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: May i ask what that "usecase" possibly could be? Because, to be honest, this sounds awkward and awful - no offense :/ if you want to change the params, go ahead and change the route and its params. what you are doing is dis-syncing the actual routes and the params you're working on. this can not be a good idea, ever.

Comment: Pagination - specifically changing the current page or page size. In neither case is a new route being called, so to keep the route parameters used elsewhere in the component synchronized with the displayed content, I had to manually add code for the purpose. There's probably a better way, but this is my first Angular 2+ project with only a few, small AngularJS projects for prior experience.

Comment: If you want to change the pageSize oder selectedPage you can either just add it to your route in the first place (would be the best solution, since a refresh of the page would result in the same content if you persist it in the route) when you call the same route just with different params, the route will not reload, it will just update the routeParams observable - or just use normal class variables for it. there's no reason to *hack* it into the route params, if they aren' route params in the first place. hope i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure this is the best way to go, but it's working for me.

Instead of `Object.create(null) as Params`, I'm creating the initial value like this:

```js
const initialValue = Object.create((this.routeParams as any).params.__proto__);
```

This creates an "empty" object whose prototype matches that of the original, private `params` object, so after calling the `convertToParamMap` function, the resulting `ParamMap` instance's internal `params` object has the `hasOwnProperty(name)` method.

Personally, I don't like calling private members from outside the object which contains them, but this works, so I'll be using it until a better option comes along.